# Sublime Text 3 - Preview in browser [localhost] using sidebar enhancement plugin

Tags: php, json, browser, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have an issue with Sublime Text 3 where I can't get the side bar enhancement plugin to preview in browser for projects on a localhost web server.

I am not the most privy with Sublime but I like the customisation and flexibility.

I have read a couple of different sites in setting the plugin up but to no avail. Maybe my lack of understanding or maybe I'm just missing something. 
Here are some the sites I've looked at for starters: 
https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements#with-absolute-paths
https://github.com/xkeshav/sublime/blob/master/settings.md
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/view-in-browser-php-file-xampp/18431/2
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/preview-in-localhost/

I've tried a few variations of the SideBarEnhancements.json script and this is what I've currently landed on using (which doesn't work anyways).

```
{
    "/applications/mamp/htdocs": 
    {
        "url_testing":"http://localhost",
        "url_production":"http://localhost"
    }
}
```

I'm also trying to use the key bindings, but since I can't even get the right click Open in Browser function to work, well I'm just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems that SideBarEnhancements.json file as articulated above does in fact work.

However how it ended up working I'm not entirely sure. In the end I just re-saved the json file and restarted Sublime which made the right click open in browser function of sidebarenhancements plugin work.
Now to fix the key bindings. Will update when possible.